# AWS public subnet vs Assigning elastic IP address to an instance of a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet, amazon-vpc, elastic-ip

What is difference between two terminologies, having a public subnet vs assigning elastic IP address to an instance of VPC over AWS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instances created in VPC public subnets will be automatically assigned a public, routable IP address and a corresponding publicly-resolvable DNS entry of the form `ip-<dash delimited address>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com`. Any ports allowed in the instance's security groups will be accessible over the Internet. The automatic address cannot be chosen. These public addresses are not persistent; when the instance is terminated, the IP address is lost.

Elastic IP addresses, by contrast, are associated with an AWS account. They can be attached to an instance. When the instance is terminated, the elastic IP can be associated with a new instance. They are persistent until manually released.

You may find the AWS docs on [VPC public addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ip-addresses) useful. Also note that EIPs have some small cost associated in some cases; see the section on Elastic IP Addresses in the [EC2 pricing docs](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).

Comment: Can I say elastic-IP give flexibility to open up single EC2 machine laying behind VPC while all ec2 machines of public subnets ends up being public ?

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand the question. Any instance in a public subnet, whether it has an EIP or not, is "opened" publicly. EIPs just offer a persistent address that can float between instances. They are better suited for use as a DNS A record, for example